# T-sql query to include attributes value in all the nodes of the xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Hope you all are doing good. i am having a requirement that i want an sql query to include attributes value in all the nodes of the xml. in the below script ID value should come in all the node as attribute .Sample code and try for your reference.

Sample Script:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLGEN(ID INT,A VARCHAR(255),B  VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO XMLGEN  SELECT 1,'a1','b1' 
                    union all SELECT 2,'a2','b2'  
                    union all SELECT 3,'a3','b3'  
                    union all SELECT 4,'a4','b4'
                    union all SELECT 5,'a5','b5'
```

query which i tried:

```
select ID as '@Attribute', * from XMLGEN  FOR XML PATH('ImportData'), TYPE,root('root')
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <ImportData Attribute="1">
    <ID>1</ID>
    <A>a1</A>
    <B>b1</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData Attribute="2">
    <ID>2</ID>
    <A>a2</A>
    <B>b2</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData Attribute="3">
    <ID>3</ID>
    <A>a3</A>
    <B>b3</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData Attribute="4">
    <ID>4</ID>
    <A>a4</A>
    <B>b4</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData Attribute="5">
    <ID>5</ID>
    <A>a5</A>
    <B>b5</B>
  </ImportData>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
  <ImportData>
    <ID Attribute="1">1</ID>
    <A Attribute="1">a1</A>
    <B Attribute="1">b1</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData>
    <ID Attribute="2">2</ID>
    <A Attribute="2">a2</A>
    <B Attribute="2">b2</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData>
    <ID Attribute="3">3</ID>
    <A Attribute="3">a3</A>
    <B Attribute="3">b3</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData>
    <ID Attribute="4">4</ID>
    <A Attribute="4">a4</A>
    <B Attribute="4">b4</B>
  </ImportData>
  <ImportData>
    <ID Attribute="5">5</ID>
    <A Attribute="5">a5</A>
    <B Attribute="5">b5</B>
  </ImportData>
</root>
```

can anyone help to  build the query?????

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    ID as [ID/@Attribute]
    ,ID as [ID]
    ,ID as [A/@Attribute]
    ,A as [A]
    ,ID as [B/@Attribute]  
    ,B as [B]
from XMLGEN  FOR XML PATH('ImportData'), TYPE,root('root')
```

Comment: Code only answers may solve the problem, but some explanation would make it much easier to understand and useful for future users.